# Excel issue with integrating string text splitter function and worksheet_change

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a piece of code that automatically separates the data scanned in from a plug&play scanner from a 2D bar-code. The data is in this format "SN1234567 7654321 PA01234-5 A B C" and I need each block of text/numbers into each own cell. Now I was successful in finding a macro online to split this text(shown below), and also a macro to automatically run A (not my macro) macro when entering data into A1. the problem is I cant get the worksheet_change sub to work with my splittext macro. Code shown below

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range

' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
' cause an alert when they are changed.
Set KeyCells = Range("A1:C10")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then

    ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
    ' changed.
    ' Place your code here.
    MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."
    Call textsplit

End If
End Sub

Sub textsplit()
Dim text As String
Dim a As Integer
Dim name As Variant
text = ActiveCell.Value
name = Split(text, " ")
For a = 0 To UBound(name)
    Cells(1, a + 1).Value = name(a)
Next a
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not really clear where you want the split values to go, but something along these lines works:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range, rng As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:C10")

    'Target can be a multi-cell range, so you need to account
    '  for that possibility
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Target)

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then

        ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
        ' changed.
        ' Place your code here.
        Debug.Print "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."

        'prevent re-activating this sub when splitting text...
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        textsplit Target
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If

    Exit Sub

haveError:
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub


Sub textsplit(rng As Range)
    Dim c As Range, arr

    For Each c In rng.Cells
        If Len(c.Value) > 0 Then
            arr = Split(c.Value, " ")
            c.Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, UBound(arr) + 1).Value = arr
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Once the cell was changed, the `ActiveCell` is no longer the target. Send the Sub the target, see below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range

' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
' cause an alert when they are changed.
Set KeyCells = Range("A1:C10")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
       Is Nothing Then

    ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
    ' changed.
    ' Place your code here.
    MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."
    Call textsplit(Target)

End If
End Sub

Sub textsplit(Target)
Dim text As String
Dim a As Integer
Dim name As Variant
text = Target.Value
name = Split(text, " ")
For a = 0 To UBound(name)
    Cells(1, a + 1).Value = name(a)
Next a
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I modified some of your code to use TextToColumns instead of textsplit() which works.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim KeyCells As Range

Set KeyCells = Range("A1:C10")

If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
        Is Nothing Then     
    MsgBox "Cell " & Target.Address & " has changed."
    Target.TextToColumns Destination:=Range(Target.Address), DataType:=xlDelimited, Space:=True

End If
End Sub
```